# Kinder phrase for "Enough of talking"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, expressions

Currently I'm working on a presentation that has a video in it.

The video is at almost the end of presentation and 'till that there's only texts and speechs of mine.

So what I'm trying to say is
There was only words and talkings in the presentation, For that
just before the video starts I want to say

"Enough of talking, let's see a video that will help us understand"
Or
"Better looking than listening, Let's see a video that will help us understand"

meanig of "it's over with boring speech lets look at the video"

but I think the audiences might take this rude of me..
Could there be a better phrase that has more manners in it?

Comment: Let's just say you're talking about baboons. After talking and presenting slides about baboons say "Now let's watch a video about baboons!" (Everyone child screams with joy and lives happily ever after).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're talking about *you* talking, this wouldn't be rude at all. I might just add a "me" in there too make it a little more natural ("That's enough of me taking, ..."). Adding "me" also helps to emphasize that you're cutting off your own speaking, which is good humor in English.

As Jason said, "a picture is worth a thousand words" is also a good expression for saying how valuable multimedia is. Altogether, I'd probably say something like:
"Ok, that's enough of me talking. They say a picture's worth a thousand words, so let's watch a video to help us understand better."

Comment: Thank yuo Drazex
The "me" part was really touching and made me inspired!

Answer (score 0):

There is a common phrase you could use in something like this: "But, anyway, **a picture is worth a thousand words**. Or, in this case, a video!"

In short, it means ([from The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-picture-is-worth-a-thousand-words.html)) that "a picture tells a story just as well as, if not better than, a lot of written words."

Unless you have a lot of experience with it, it's always better to express positivity over something than to try to make a joke about something having been negative. So, just express excitement about the video and that's what should be picked up on by the audience.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about not talking needs to be done with Very Few Words, otherwise it is boring in itself. I often hear someone ellaborating over how brief they are going to be.

Let’s look at ...
Let us see ...